# BeautifulSoup: Difficulty accessing correct table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup4 to scrape a page and the following function is giving me 2 issues:

```
def getTeamRoster(teamURL):
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(teamURL).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    teamPlayers = []
    #second table
    corebody = soup.find(id = "corebody")
    teamTable = corebody.table.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling
    print(teamTable)
    tableBody = teamTable.find('tbody')
    print(tableBody)
    tableRows = tableBody.findAll('tr')
```

1) When I call ".next_sibling" only 4 times (as above), I *seem* to get the correct table.  However, the table tag I'm trying to access is the 6th table within the #corebody ID.  When I call ".next_sibling" 5 times, I get -1 from BeautifulSoup, indicating the table I've requested doesn't exist?  I thought you normally get None back when this happens.  Any idea why calling ".next_sibling" 5 times isn't working as expected?

URL is `http://modules.ussquash.com/ssm/pages/leagues/Team_Information.asp?id=11325`

2) tableBody = teamTable.find('tbody')
is giving me some trouble.  When I print tableBody, I get None but I'm not sure why this is happening (there's definitely a  tag within the table I'm accessing).

Ideas?

Thanks for the help,
bclayman

Comment: `tbody` is possibly generated by browser. try save the actual html file instead of viewing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can get the players table using `pandas.read_html`:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://modules.ussquash.com/ssm/pages/leagues/Team_Information.asp?id=11325'
tables = pd.read_html(requests.get(url).content)
tables[4]
                            \n\t\t\t\tPlayers\n\t\t\t           City Gender  SinglesRating TeamPosition  Expiration Win/Loss    P Registered Code Ref. Exam
0                                         Browne,Noah        Taunton      M           5.56            1  02/29/2016   14 / 4    -   08/28/14    -       NaN
1                                      Ellis,Thornton            rye      M           4.27           10  02/29/2016    0 / 9    -   08/28/14    -      pass
2                                          Line,James    Glastonbury      M           4.25           10  02/29/2016    2 / 7    -   08/28/14    -       NaN
3                                   Desantis,Scott J.        Sudbury      M           5.08            2  02/29/2016   9 / 10    -   08/28/14    -      pass
4                                    Bahadori,Cameron    Great Falls      M           4.97            3  01/12/2016   3 / 10    -   11/05/14    -      pass
5                                       Groot,Michael       Victoria      M           4.76            4  02/29/2016   5 / 11    -   08/28/14    -       NaN
6                                       Ehsani,Darian      Greenwich      M           4.76            5  02/29/2016   6 / 13    -   08/28/14    -      pass
7                                          Kardon,Max         Weston      M           4.83            6  02/29/2016   5 / 14    -   08/28/14    -      pass
8                                          Van,Jeremy            NaN      M           4.66            7  02/29/2016   5 / 13    -   08/28/14    -       NaN
9                              Southmayd,Alexander T.         Boston      M           4.91            8  02/29/2016   13 / 6    -   08/28/14    -      pass
10                                 Cacouris,Stephen A         Alpine      M           4.68            9  02/29/2016   9 / 10    -   08/28/14    -      pass
11                                  Groot,Christopher       Edmonton      M           4.62            -  02/29/2016    0 / 2    -   08/28/14    -       NaN
12                                Mack,Peter D. (sub)     N. Eastham      M           3.94            -  02/29/2016    0 / 1    -   11/23/14    -       NaN
13                               Shrager,Nathaniel O.       Stanford      M           0.00            -  02/29/2016    0 / 0    -   08/28/14    -       NaN
14                                Woolverton,Peter C.  Chestnut Hill      M           4.06            -  02/29/2016    1 / 0    -   08/28/14    -       NaN
15  Total Players: 15 Average singles rating: 4.36...            NaN    NaN            NaN          NaN         NaN      NaN  NaN        NaN  NaN       NaN
```

Comment: tbh i'd never tried it before answering this question!

Answer (score 1):

Use `soup.select`

One liner:

```
[i.get_text() for i in soup.select('#corebody table tr td') if 'Won' in i.get_text() or 'Lost' in i.get_text()]`
```

Long version:

```
for i in soup.select('#corebody table tr td'):
    if 'Won' in i.get_text() or 'Lost' in i.get_text():
        print i.get_text()`
```

`[u'Won 7-2',
 u'Won 5-4',
 u'Lost 1-8',
 u'Lost 1-8',
 u'Won 8-1',
 u'Lost 3-6',
 u'Won 7-2',
 u'Lost 0-9',
 u'Lost 1-8',
 u'Won 5-4',
 u'Lost 1-8',
 u'Lost 2-7',
 u'Won 8-1',
 u'Lost 3-6',
 u'Lost 4-5',
 u'Lost 4-5',
 u'Lost 1-8',
 u'Lost 4-5',
 u'Won 6-3']`